# Reformat email address. Capitalize first and last name. Remove domain. Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Just working on a script to generate a report. 
Data is form submissions via google form. Emails are collected in form, as well as other data.

ALL email addresses are structured too.
Firstname.Lastname@email-domain.co.uk

For the report, I wanted to put in peoples names, not emails.

Here is what I've come up with, and it does work, but I'm new to Javascript and scripts for google. So want to try to get things right, or find out where I'm going wrong. I don't want to write lots of scripts and put them together to find they take too long with too much data and fail.

```
 var cleanName = names[i].replace("@email-domain.co.uk","");
  var cleanName = cleanName.replace("."," ");
  var cleanName = cleanName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cleanName.slice(1);
  var space = cleanName.search(" ");
  var cleanName = cleanName.substr(0,space+1)+ cleanName.charAt(space+1).toUpperCase() + cleanName.slice(space+2);
```

I tried for about an hour to get it to work without the space var. But just couldn't do it. 
not that it's the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It just dawned on me that you could actually trim this down a little further, by using the `.join` method for arrays:

```
var namePieces = names[i].replace(/@.+$/, "").split(".");

for (i=0; i<namePieces.length; i++) {
    namePieces[i] = namePieces[i].replace(/^[a-z]/, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}

var cleanName = namePieces.join(" ");
```

. . . or, if you are returning the `cleanName` value, for that last line, you could just use:

```
return namePieces.join(" ");
```

That would actually just convert the first letter of each element in the `namePieces` array to uppercase and then `join` all of the updated elements together, with a space separating each element.

---

**Original Answer**

Here's an alternate approach . . . based on your code, you could do this:

```
var namePieces = names[i].replace(/@.+$/, "").split(".");
var cleanName = "";

for (i=0; i<namePieces.length; i++) {
    cleanName += (i > 0) ? " " : "";
    cleanName += namePieces[i].replace(/^[a-z]/, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Now, let me step through the code . . .   :)

```
var namePieces = names[i].replace(/@.+$/, "").split(".");
```

This takes the current email address, strips off everything after the `@`, and splits the remaining values, into an array, every time it hits a `.`

The result of your sample data `Firstname.Lastname@email-domain.co.uk`, would be this array: `["Firstname", "Lastname"]`

After that, it goes through each item in the array and adds a space to the existing `cleanName` value, if it is not the first element in the `namePieces` array:

```
cleanName += (i > 0) ? " " : "";
```

Then it takes the current name "piece" and, if it's first character is a lowercase letter, replaces it with the uppercase version of itself, and adds it to the current `cleanName` value:

```
cleanName += namePieces[i].replace(/^[a-z]/, function(match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

Two things to note about this approach:

1. It skips the replace if it not a lowercase letter for a little extra speed.  If you need to account for non-alpha characters (other languages, symbols, numbers), this regex would have to be altered to either accept any character (i.e., `/^./`) or change the set of acceptable characters in the regex.
2. This approach will also pick up other variations of the names in the email address . . . for example:

   `Firstname.M.Lastname@email-domain.co.uk` would result in `Firstname M Lastname`
   `Firstname.Lastname.Jr@email-domain.co.uk` would result in `Firstname Lastname Jr`

   So that might add a little extra flexibility.

Comment: thank you for the reply and the concise explanation of the code. This is using regexp? If so, I've not studied that yet, I've looked at it, but it really confused me, + other things to learn in meantime. 

Email address are always uniform, lowercase, firstname.surname@

off to try your suggestion now. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, it uses very basic RegExp . . . the first is `/@.+$/`, which means, "find the first occurrence of `@` and all of the other characters between it and the end of the string (and there must be at least 1 there)".  The second is `/^[a-z]/`, which means, "start at the beginning of the string and match the first character, if it is a lowercase letter".

Comment: As for the email format, it will handle your standard . . . just pointing out that it will also handle a few other variations, should they ever happen to pop up.   :)

Comment: Thank you once again :) I'll give it a whirl and get back to you.

Comment: So i tried to do a good comparative test on all 3 verions. Here is what I have so far.

V1 - Mine
[14-02-05 22:31:01:327 GMT] Start clean names - [14-02-05 22:31:12:558 GMT] Finished clean names
[14-02-05 22:31:38:269 GMT] Execution succeeded [28.51 seconds total runtime]

V2 talemyn 1.0
[14-02-05 22:39:23:723 GMT] Start clean names - [14-02-05 22:39:25:175 GMT] Finished clean names
[14-02-05 22:39:50:966 GMT] Execution succeeded [3.359 seconds total runtime]

V3 talemyn 2.0
Keeps exceeding execution time and not finishing

Comment: `.join()` can be slow . . . that was my one worry about that last approach.  Glad that the first approach ended up being faster for you, though.   :)